# Mac search and back up

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a client bringing in their pc to get it wash and reloaded, and they wanted their photos before that happened.

What a good script that would search a mac's file structure and only copy files "img*.jpg" to a folder on a drive?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` by specifying a name pattern and executing `cp` on the matched files:

```
find . -type f -name "img*.jpg" -exec cp {} ../backup \;
```

Comment: I have a bad feeling I need to do more than just state ../backup . I'm rather new to appplescript and more at home with basic of vbs

Comment: @JohnD.Palmer This is a bash command, you can execute it in the Terminal. Sorry, didn't see the AppleScript tag.